# Is there a straightforward way to define a differentiable structure on a localic manifold?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, locales

I'd ideally like a categorical definition of differentiability that can then be trivially translated into locales. Barring this, I'm still interested in whether the notion make sense for locales.

Comment: If the goal is just to get a general abstract notion of a category of smooth objects, then see, for example, http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/synthetic+differential+geometry.

Comment: This is an interesting question. SDT may be the answer but it is not obvious to me that it is the necessary one. Some elementary investigation of differentiable functions $f:{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ from a localic viewpoint would seem to be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what I've been working on.  I've tried a few approaches.

Grothendieck gives a definition of formal smoothness which can be translated into just about any category.  The problem is that, for the definition to be interesting, it relies on the fact that commutative rings sometimes have non-trivial nilpotents.

G also gives a definition of smoothness which doesn't rely on nilpotents necessarily.  This is what I've been working on.  It's possible to give the definition, but it's not immediately clear whether it's interesting in the sense that there are some arrows in Loc which are smooth and some which are not.  There is some promise, though, in that, smooth arrows are flat and not everything in the category of locales is flat.

What got you interested in this by the way?  Feel free to email me.

Comment: We can't email you because you haven't provided an email or web address on your profile. Anyway, this is you opportunity to give a taster of whatever light you have to throw on this interesting question.

Comment: OK.  Here's the latest: